# Inheritance of variables in callbacks

Tags: node.js, multithreading, event-loop, asynccallback

I have the problem that I receive several events in a nodejs worker in very short intervals. These call several callbacks, as shown in the figure, which must access the parameters of the event in each callback. The structures of the callbacks can not be changed, so the transfer as a parameter is not possible.

[image]

My idea was to store the parameters in a global object and access them via the "event-loop" identifier.
Unfortunately there seems to be no such identifier.

Another idea was to inherit the parameters as a global variable for all callbacks within the event. However, I did not find how to make such a variable inheritable for the other callbacks.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem?